# Android retrieve theme attribute

Tags: android, attributes, background, themes, selector

I have custom theme:

```
<style name="SomeTheme" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/some_selector</item>
</style>
```

Now I'm dynamically creating LinearLayout via code and I want to set it's background to the value of android:listSelector. How do I retrieve it? I've tried playing with `getTheme().resolveAttribute()`, but unfortunetely - with no success.

*Note: It's just simplified example. I have to do it via code, using `?android:listSelector` as `android:background` in the xml layout doesn't solve the problem.*